# "from __future__ import annotations" results in "annotations is not defined" in VSCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, visual-studio-code

```
    from __future__ import annotations
SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined
```

I get this error when I try to run my code in the VSCode terminal. I never have this error when I ran my code with PyCharm. I just don't understand what is making it not work in VSCode.

I'm using Python 3.7 as my project interpreter.

Comment: We need some more information to help with this. How is your vscode terminal set up? What python interpreter is it using (system, user, local)? What plugin are you using for python? What OS are you using? And the same questions for pycharm.

Comment: It sounds like Python 3.7 is not what is being run in your VSCode terminal.  You can check this by looking at the start of your console session (you'll see something like "Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14" as the first line).  You can also `import sys; print(sys.version)`.

Comment: How are you running your code "_in the VSCode terminal_"? Did you do right-click > _Run Python File in Terminal_ or did you use the debugger or did you manually enter `python3 yourfile.py` on the terminal? There should be no problem with Python 3.7, unless you weren't actually using Python 3.7.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister in the bottom left corner, it says i am using 3.7.2. I also changed the version to 3.7.2 in the command palette, but when I did what you said with print(sys.version), it prints 3.5, and I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: @PeterH I am sorry I do not know how to answer these questions. My vscode terminal is the same one that I got when I first installed vscode. I am using windows 10

Comment: @GinoMempin I am manually entering python3 myfile.py, and  I have tried right-clicking run python file in terminal and that doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: "_I am manually entering python3 myfile.py_": What does `python3 -V` give you? It should show 3.7 if you really are using 3.7. If it isn't, maybe you installed it as `python3.7`..? If it still isn't, then looks you need to fix your env first so that you use Python 3.7 because you seem to have a problem here: "_when I did what you said with print(sys.version), it prints 3.5_".

Comment: @GinoMempin yeah python3 -v prints python 3.6.5. How do I change my env to python 3.7?

Comment: @BemjaminZhuo Unfortunately, I can't really say how to fix either PyCharm or VSCode (I don't use either of them).  My guess is that this going to have to do a lot with your terminal environment.  You need to make sure that Python37 is on your path first (see [this](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/) on how to edit your environment).  That way when you type "python3", the python3.exe found in version 3.7 is found first.  VSCode is not in charge of your terminal settings, so it's up to you to get that part right. :-(

Comment: And just to be clear, it's "C:\Program Files\Python 3.7" that should be on your PATH.  You should've had an option to add this to your PATH when you installed.  It may be that what you really need to do is remove the other Python installations from your PATH.

Comment: It depends largely on how you setup/installed Python on your machine. Start with making sure `python3` points to Python3.7 when running *outside* of VSCode (like the suggestion above to set PATH properly). When that works, I then suggest going through [Using Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) if you haven't already (if you already did, it's worth re-reading). If you still are having problems, there are already [a lot of other posts here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=vscode%20terminal%20python%20version) on that topic.

Comment: Why not just change the interpreter by pressing `ctrl+shift+P`, then type in `Python: Select Interpreter` and choose one of the Python versions aviable? You could also set a different Python version by modifying your `settings.json` and adding the line `"python.pythonPath": "path/to/another/Python_executable"`. That works in your global `settings.json` and in your workspace settings.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you created a virtual environment and selected that as your interpreter, typing something like `python3 myfile.py` will not guarantee you are using the Python interpreter you selected in VS Code (that's under the control of your shell, not VS Code). Make sure to use `Run Python File in Terminal` as that will make sure your file is run using the selected Python interpreter.