# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-g22gfh_9/lazy-object-proxy/ on jetson nano

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, nvidia-jetson-nano

[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3A5tvO9UbwY&ab_channel=JetsonHacks)

i follow this youtuber try to install Visual Studio Code on  jetson nano

This happened when I used this command:`./installVSCodeWithPython.sh`,i recieve this:

by the way the link of youtube is up,English is not very good, please forgive me!

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-g22gfh_9/lazy-object-proxy/setup.py", line 146, in <module>
        distclass=BinaryDistribution,
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 372, in __init__
        _Distribution.__init__(self, attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 281, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 528, in finalize_options
        ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2324, in load
        return self.resolve()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2330, in resolve
        module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-g22gfh_9/lazy-object-proxy/.eggs/setuptools_scm-7.0.5-py3.6.egg/setuptools_scm/__init__.py", line 5
        from __future__ import annotations
        ^
    SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined
   
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-g22gfh_9/lazy-object-proxy/
Collecting black*
```

If there is more information needed, I will provide  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54993232/from-future-import-annotations-results-in-annotations-is-not-defined-in). This seems to be caused by the incorrect selection of the Python interpreter. However, you are currently in the process of installing vscode, which seems to be a mixed error. I think it is more reasonable to change the download method.

You can refer to the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux) for details about installing vscode and python. It's more official.

Here is the download page on [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) and [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/).